# 24V to 5V step down voltage regulator with LM2678

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, buck, step-down

[image]

Reference: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2678.pdf

I have constructed the circuit above attempting to step down the DC voltage from 24V to 5V. But I keep getting 8.3V as the output voltage. It is such a simple circuit so I am not sure which part of the circuit can go wrong. Can someone give me some suggestions as to where the problem is?

---

Additional Information

Parts:

- Schottky diode (part no: STPS1545FP) https://www.digikey.com.au/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/STPS1545FP/2170952
- Inductor 22uH (part no: 70-TJ32UEB220MHT) https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Dale/TJ32UEB220MHT?qs=6TYuK4dfxu2UnX3v2JgzdQ%3D%3D

The LM2678 I got is the 5V version. I only measured the output voltage under no load condition.

It only outputs 5V up to 16V input. After the input voltage passes 16V. the output voltage increases as the input voltage increases.

Comment: More details would be helpful. What is your load and how much current is it using ? What are the specs (or part numbers) of the diode and the inductor that you used ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the 5.0 version? Are all the other components the same as shown in the typical app schematic? Can you provide PCB and/or an assembly photo?

Comment: what voltage are you seeing at the "boost"/bootstrap pin of the IC? Do you have an oscilloscope you can use to check that pin?

Comment: Repeat the test with loaded output to see if it behaves the same. Operating in DCM might cause some internal things. Or you might have some broken components or even a fake chip.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the cause of your issue or might cause you issues later on, but you probably need a bigger inductance.

Refer to the inductor value selection guide in the datasheet:

[image: LM2576 Inductor selection chart]
[image: Inductor selection]

For example, if you want to sustain a load current of 1.5A with an input voltage of 24V, you will need an inductor belonging to the *H220* category, meaning an inductor of 220µH.

The lowest recommended value is 47µH, which would only work up to 9V input voltage, and your inductor is only 22µH.